# Importing script via script tag and using function from that script within react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application using the teller.io API. I have to import a script from them to initiate authentication within my react app, as they have no react library.

After adding the script to the DOM, I have to use a function from it. However, React won't recognize the function as it's only defined at runtime when the script is added.

The following is my solution, and it works, but I know this cannot be a good way to accomplish this so if anyone can recommend a proper solution that'd be amazing.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://cdn.teller.io/connect/connect.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    var tellerConnect = window.TellerConnect.setup({
        applicationId: "Your application ID e.g app_xxxxxx",
        onInit: function() {
          console.log("Teller Connect has initialized");
        },
        // Part 3. Handle a successful enrollment's accessToken
        onSuccess: function(enrollment) {
          console.log("User enrolled successfully", enrollment.accessToken);
        },
        onExit: function() {
          console.log("User closed Teller Connect");
        }
    });

    var el = document.getElementById("myButton");
    el.addEventListener("click", function() {
        // tellerConnect.open();
    });
    
  }, []);
```

Line 6, with the "window.TellerConnect.setup is what I'd like to fix/replace with a more proper solution.

Teller.io docs for this script/setup can be found at: [Teller Connect](https://teller.io/docs/teller-connect#part-one)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "React won't recognize" is not the problem – React doesn't care. The problem is you're not waiting for the script to load before calling `setup`...

Answer (score 2):

A pattern (a hook and a pure-JS loader) like this might work for you.

This doesn't take into account multiple components attempting to use the API with e.g. different application IDs.

```
function loadScript(elementId, src) {
  if (!document.getElementById(elementId)) {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    script.id = elementId;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }
}

/**
 * Ensure the Teller Connect script is loaded.
 *
 * Returns the `window.TellerConnect` object once it exists.
 */
function loadTellerConnect() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {

    function check() {
      if (window.TellerConnect) {
        return resolve(window.TellerConnect);
      }
      loadScript('teller-script', 'https://cdn.teller.io/connect/connect.js');
      setTimeout(check, 100);
    }

    check();
  });
}

/**
 * Load and configure Teller Connect.
 * @returns The Teller API (or null if it hasn't yet loaded).
 */
function useTellerAPI(setupArgs) {
  const [tellerApi, setTellerApi] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    loadTellerConnect().then((tellerApi) => {
      tellerApi.setup(setupArgs);
      setTellerApi(tellerApi);
    });
  }, [setupArgs]);
  return tellerApi;
}

function MyComponent() {
  const tellerConnect = useTellerAPI({
    applicationId: 'Your application ID e.g app_xxxxxx',
  });
  return (
    <button onClick={() => tellerConnect?.open()} disabled={!tellerConnect}>
      Open Teller
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is much cleaner, thanks!

Comment: Only issue I ran into with this solution, was I had to modify the "useTellerApi" function a bit. I had to change "tellerApi.setup(setupArgs);" and "setTellerApi(tellerApi);" to just "setTellerApi(tellerApi.setup(setupArgs));". Reason being, the TellerConnect object does not have an "open()" function, but the object returned by "TellerConnect.setup()" does

Comment: Ah, sure. I didn't read the docs that thoroughly. Glad I could help anyway!